# user-friendly application entry points in MATLAB or SciLab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, graphics, windows-xp, scilab

I have an application I would like to write in either MATLAB or SciLab. This question is not about the application itself, but about entry points.

I would like a way for users to click on an icon or shortcut or whatever, and execute the following steps:

1. If MATLAB or SciLab is not running, launch it and wait until the launch is complete. If it is running already, proceed to step 2.
2. Run my application (MATLAB or SciLab script)

Any suggestions?

---

If the only way to do this is from within MATLAB/SciLab (vs. at the command-line) then I'll live with that, but I need to know how to do it.

Put yourself in a user's shoes: You know nothing about MATLAB or SciLab, and a coworker has given you this application that runs under MATLAB/SciLab to use.

What is the easiest way to get that user to be able to use the application, without having to teach them MATLAB commands or setting the MATLAB path or anything like that. (Ditto for SciLab.)

Comment: I think how you approach step 1 is OS dependent, so you might want to let us know what OS you're developing for (and perhaps tag it so?)

Comment: ah, thanks. It's Windows XP. tagged appropriately.

Comment: Do you actually need the MATLAB UI or do you just want the ability to run M code scripts?

Comment: Forget anything you know about GUIs in MATLAB; this is not about the application. I want to be able to launch a script or GUI or whatever in MATLAB by clicking on an icon/shortcut in Windows, or running a batch file. And I don't want a second MATLAB window to open if one is already open.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Matlab from the command line. So you could wrap the command line call in a shortcut and all the user would have to do is double click it. I would take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16B8X/) and see if these use-cases will help, although I suspect they will.

You can do things like:

```
 matlab -nosplash -nodesktop  -r 'plot(0:.1:pi,sin(0:.1:pi))'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this always starts another instance of MATLAB, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Think editors / IDEs: when a good editor is open, and you double click on a source file to open the editor, if it's already open, the currently-running instance opens the file in question.

Comment: @Jason-S Oh I see, sorry. why not use the Matlab compiler to create a standalone application? http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f7-996249.html

Comment: @jason Ok last suggestion: Use the Matlab API and call the evaluate command from C++ to run your script. Open the Matlab engine instance with http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/engsetvisible.html . Then the nodesktop instance will be hidden. All you can see is your GUI, etc. Then you can kill matlab once you are done with it. While this will still have two instances, it will be invisible to the end user. If that isn't acceptable, then I'm out of ideas sorry!

Comment: @Chris: "call the evaluate command from C++" -- C++ is out. Thanks though.

Comment: @jason even for just a wrapper program to call the script? Too bad. Well, good luck!